# How can we track a field or fields on Managed Package Objects?

Tags: managed-package, history-tracking

How can we track a field or fields on Managed Package Objects that have been installed in my org?

If field Tracking History is not enabled for the Object by AppExchange Managed Product provider.

Any suggestions and help will be appreciated!

> Note: I am in contact with AppExchange Managed Product provider but still not getting any useful information.

Answer (score 2):

**You can.**

Be sure you do not forget to edit the object and enable field history tracking for the object. Else you will be able to select fields to track but nothing will happen (no history object activated, no related list)

Answer (score -1):

You cannot programatically or from the managed package change these things.

The sys-admin of each org need to do this by himself manually

My suggestion is to create a very good step by step manual for the sys-admin to do that.

Good luck.

Comment: What you mean by sys admin? Manage Package provider or org admin??

Comment: org admin - this is for the owner of the org to decide

Comment: No in manage package object its not available for admin too...